# JSF: how to add TH to each row?

Tags: jsf, html-table

I need this HTML output:

```
<tr>
    <th>...</th>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>...</th>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
etc...
```

I don't do JSF much and here's the JSF I'm working with:

```
<h:dataTable>
    <h:column>...</h:column>
    <h:column>...</h:column>
    <h:column>...</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

That, alas, doesn't give me any THs just 3 TDs. So I then tried this:

```
<h:dataTable>
    <h:column><f:facet name="header">...</f:facet></h:column>
    <h:column>...</h:column>
    <h:column>...</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

But that only gives me a TH in the first row, not every subsequent row.

Is there a way to do with with JSF without having to write some custom component of some sorts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How important is it to have an actual TH in each row?  If this is just for styling purposes you might be able to accomplish what you want with h:dataTable's "columnClasses" to give the first column a different CSS class.

```
<h:dataTable columnClasses="firstColumn">
   ... h:columns ...
</h:dataTable>
```

If you absolutely must have a TH element in each row, I can't think of a way to do this with h:dataTable, but you could use <ui:repeat> instead.  This will work like old-school <c:forEach> where you render the <table>/<tr> yourself.  For example:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="row">
  <tr>
    <th><h:outputText value="#{row.foo}"/></th>
    <td><h:outputText value="#{row.bar}"/></td>
  </tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

Hope this helps!